# Melt data with randomized columns within rows

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, tidyr

I conducted a conjoint design survey with the hopes of using the [cjoint package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cjoint/cjoint.pdf). The example data from the cjoint package is formatted as:

```
head(model)
  CaseID contest_no          FeatEd             FeatJob
1      4          1     high school               Nurse
2      4          1       no formal Child care provider
3      4          2 graduate degree            Gardener
4      4          2       4th grade Construction worker
5      4          3     high school               Nurse
6      4          3  college degree Child care provider
                  FeatLang Chosen_Immigrant
1 tried English but unable              Yes
2         used interpreter               No
3           fluent English               No
4           fluent English              Yes
5           broken English              Yes
6           fluent English               No
```

"Case ID" stands for each respondent, and "contest_no" is for individual tasks each respondent completes. In this case, each respondent completed 5 tasks (tasks 1 through 3 visible), with each task comparing 2 profiles. Each profile varied by the attributes "FeatEd", "Featjob", "FeatLang". The selected profile is listed as "Chosen_Immigrant", with an indicator for Yes or No.

My current data are:

- Collapsed by respondent. All tasks, profiles, and attributes on the same row.
- Randomized by attributes within each row.

For example:

```
has[1:3,12:16]
              F.1.1
1     Affordability
2 Community Support
3            Height
                                                          F.1.1.1
1 Affordable units will be built off-site, elsewhere in the city.
2                        Most people in the community support it.
3                                                       3 stories
          F.1.2                                F.1.1.2             F.1.3
1 Party Support    Local Republican Party supports it. Community Support
2       Parking All residents will park on the street.     Affordability
3      Location                   In your neighborhood     Affordability
```

F.1.1 stands for the attribute title for Task 1. F.1.1.1 is the attribute value for Task 1 for Profile 1. F.1.2.1 (not shown) is the attribute value for Task 1 for Profile 2. F.1.2. is the title for Task 1, Attribute 2. F.1.1.2 is the attribute value for Task 2 for Profile 1. And so on...

As I understand, to match my data frame to that of the cjoint example, I need to:

1. Sort each row by a defined order for the Attributes. e.g., c("Affordability", "Party Support",...)
2. Using each Attribute's position in the row, grab their relevant levels offered for each Profile. For F.1.1. "Affordability", grab the compared F.1.1.1 and F.1.2.1. Group them next to each other, by row.
3. Reshape my data frame from wide to long, so that row ids run by respondent and task, and the column names are the attributes, with cells representing attribute levels.

I think I can figure out Step 3 with either reshape2 or tidyr. However, any help on sorting by column within row given cell value and grabbing relevant other cells within the row would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should begin by melting. Get it so that each row is defined by an ID, Task and Profile. Then you just need to sort rows within an ID rather than sort columns.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Gregor! As stated, I've been moving in from the other direction. I'll start focusing on the reshaping issue. Maybe then I can better describe where I am getting hung-up.

Comment: Sorting things columns within a row is do-able, but not common so it's difficult to do well. However, with dplyr, sorting rows within a particular grouping is very easy. I also thing having a column called "Task" that has values 1 2 and 3 and another column called Profile with values 1, 2 and 3 will make your data much more understandable (for those of us who might try to help you) than the current `F.x.y.z` format. As-is, even with your explanation, it's very difficult to understand what's going on.

Comment: Also, it is nice to see your data in a readable format like this, but sharing data using `dput` will make it copy/pasteable into R, which helps a lot for making it easy to test code to help you.

Comment: I'll look into dplyr for the grouping function. And yes, you're absolutely correct about the confusing column names. They are the result of the Qualtrics workaround I had to employ for the conjoint design. The confusion is mutual. Re dput, I'll look into it. This is my first post, but I understand that quality posting = quality answers. Thanks again!

Comment: The dput doesn't require looking into, just paste the result of `dput(head(mydata))` into your question. But if you could get one melt in first, that might be best.